# Vector Resetting (Emptying)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, scope, undefined-behavior

Long story short I have a 3 dimensional array of objects, each with vectors of pointers to neighbouring objects within the array, and for some reason, after initialization these vectors of pointers are empty the next time request data from them.

I'm trying to represent vertices within a subdivided cube. Each node is a class represented as such:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Vertex {
public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    vector<Vertex*> DiagNeighbours;
    vector<Vertex*> DirectNeighbours;
    vector<Vertex*> ExtNeighbours;

    Vertex(float x, float y, float z) : position(glm::vec3(x, y, z)) { }
};
```

To save time at the cost of memory I store pointers to all of its neighbours. It's diagnol neighbours, its direct neighbours, and its extended neighbours (direct neighbours two node lengths away).

I have another class representing the scene I have built. It stores all of the cubes vertices, initializes them, and will eventually manipulate their data. It's set up as such (its a little long and repetitive so feel free to skip it after the second entire array traversal):

```
#include "Vertex.h"

class Scene {
    Vertex vertices[8][8][8];

public: 
    Scene() {
        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    vertices[z][y][x] = Vertex(glm::vec3(x, y, z)*cubeScale);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    if(x != 7)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y][x + 1]);
                    if(x != 0)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y][x - 1]);
                    if(y != 7)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y + 1][x]);
                    if(y != 0)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y - 1][x]);
                    if(z != 7)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 1][y][x]);
                    if(z != 0)
                        vertices[z][y][x].DirectNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 1][y][x]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    if (y != 7) {
                        if(x != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y + 1][x + 1]);
                        if(x != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y + 1][x - 1]);
                    }
                    if (y != 0) {
                        if (x != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y - 1][x + 1]);
                        if (x != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y - 1][x - 1]);
                    }
                    if (z != 7) {
                        if (x != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 1][y][x + 1]);
                        if (x != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 1][y][x - 1]);
                    }
                    if (z != 0) {
                        if (x != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 1][y][x + 1]);
                        if (x != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 1][y][x - 1]);
                    }
                    if (z != 7) {
                        if (y != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 1][y + 1][x]);
                        if (y != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 1][y - 1][x]);
                    }
                    if (z != 0) {
                        if (y != 7)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 1][y + 1][x]);
                        if (y != 0)
                            vertices[z][y][x].DiagNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 1][y - 1][x]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    if (x != 6)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y][x + 2]);
                    if (x != 1)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y][x - 2]);
                    if (y != 6)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y + 2][x]);
                    if (y != 1)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z][y - 2][x]);
                    if (z != 6)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z + 2][y][x]);
                    if (z != 1)
                        vertices[z][y][x].ExtNeighbours.push_back(&vertices[z - 2][y][x]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //By the time we enter this function the vectors are empty
    void Simulate() {
        for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    masses[z][y][x]->velocity += ProcessVelocity(*(masses[z][y][x]));
                    masses[z][y][x]->position += masses[z][y][x]->velocity * deltaTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As of the very last line of this constructor, everything is populated. All three vectors are initialized and filled, sizes 12, 6 and 6 respectively as I would expect. The problem now lies that by the time I leave this constructor all of the vectors of pointers that I had sent so much effort filling are emptied. The strangest part being that the position variables are still set so I know that the objects are still the same, its just the vector data that has disappeared.

In advance I am sorry if this has been asked before (I have honestly tried scouring stackoverflow for the answer to this, mostly looking for reasons a vector may be emptying itself), and for the fact that I am almost certain that it is something simple I am overlooking, like something leaving scope that I'm not seeing. Thanks in advance as well for all of your help.

**Updated Info**

To try to help uncover the problem the storage and accessing of scene in my main function for the program.

```
vector<Scene*> scenes;
unsigned int currentScene = 0;

int main() {
    scenes.push_back(&Scene());
    while(true) {
        scenes[currentScene]->Simulate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like I was able to fix the problem by changed my `vertices` array to an array of pointers and allocating each `Vertex` object on the heap using `vertices[z][y][x] = new Vertex(x, y, z)`. So I guess it was a scope issue? With that being said if anyone could explain to me why I might have encountered this problem it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Assuming your scene object was still in scope what you have seems like it would work. Hard to say without a complete example of how you are constructing a scene and where you've determined your vectors are empty. The classes you show and the way they are used wouldn't compile as you have no default constructor shown for Vertex and making an array of them requires that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, that's what I thought, but there has got to be something... I have provided more information as to the storage and accessing of the scene object within main, but from what I can see I don't see it going out of scope either

Comment: `scenes.push_back(&Scene());` pushes the address of a temporary that ceases to exist at the end of that line. `scenes.push_back(new Scene());` if you must use pointers. There's nothing in your example that seems to require it. This works fine: https://ideone.com/EI89wR

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   `Vertices` is a normal array not a vector, it can't be resized.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Awesome, you were totally right, allocating the scene on the heap totally worked. Although if scene was a temporary address that ceased to exists why is it that all of the other data was preserved, like the position of the vertices? Also I had totally forgotten for a moment why I needed pointers, just remembered it was for polymorphism (simulate is gonna be virtual)

Comment: @RetiredNinja -- ok, I see it now.

Comment: @Ryoku -- *if scene was a temporary address that ceased to exists why is it that all of the other data was preserved, like the position of the vertices?* -- Undefined behavior.  You make this kind of mistake in C++, expect anything to happen, including "work".

Comment: @Ryoku There's nothing to stop you from accessing a destroyed object, it's undefined behavior, but the vectors would be empty because their destructor was called and that's what it does.

Comment: Oh I see. I love c++ but undefined behavior seems to produce the most "interesting" stories, thanks for all of your help guys